# chm (compiled html) files only readable half the time

Tags: windows-vista, chm

Is there a way to fix chm files?

Most of the time I receive them, **I can read the index but not the content**.

That is, I can open them up and see the table of contents down the left navigation pane, but when I click any of the topics in the list, nothing happens.

I can't tell if it's because they have not been compiled correctly or if it's a problem with my (Vista) machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommended a program called **HelpExplorer** in another [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/31609/increasing-font-size-on-windows-help-file-chm).

Answer (score 6):

This annoyed me at first as well, you are likely experiencing the same thing. Right-click the `.chm` file and at the bottom you will see an **unblock** button, click it then hit apply. Microsoft automatically blocks you from running certain files downloaded on the internet for your safety (or annoyance):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can actually open it and read the index but the content part is not visible.

Comment: is there a pound sign (#) in the filename? Windows also has trouble with those.

Comment: I haven't noticed that.

Comment: the question is about chm, not pdf.

Comment: @Natrium, the file type in the picture does not matter. It was to show the unblock method. It doesn't work any differently on a chm file...

Answer (score 5):

.chm files cannot be opened from the network (security implications).
Copy the localy and you'll be able to open them up without a problem.

Comment: This is probably the problem. I know I've run into this exact issue in the past.

Comment: yup, this might be it.

Comment: the files are always local.

Comment: If the files are always local, then which folder are they in? I've also ben incases where the .chm file has to be placed in one of the trusted/safe locations, such as My Documents.